# (solved) ISO Elementary Update (HWE Stacks, linux 4.8)

Tags: system-installation, kernel, iso

I was thinking, is there an update ISO with the new HWE Stacks (based on Ubuntu 16.04.2) with the kernel 4.8 ??

I have issue installing Loki on my Skylake - Optimus laptop, with the kernel 4.4, it won't install even with kernel parameters such as ACPI=off or nomodeset...

Many thanks !

Comment: What's the  make & model of your laptop?

Comment: it's a laptop customized from a uk sellers.
The cpu is a 6700HQ and the GPU is a nvidia 950GTX

Comment: Are you able to boot into Live Mode from USB?

Comment: yep, won't boot even with different kernel parameter such as ACPI=OFF or nomodeset.
With other distro with kernel before the 4.8, i needed to set ACPI=OFF or nomodeset to boot, then update the kernel, but it's not working with Loki

Comment: Thanks ! I manage to boot on live cd, perform the installation. I update to the kernel 4.8 using: sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 but i tried to install the nvidia drivers and the prime indicator plus, but it crashed the system and cannot boot. But this worked on a friend's computer So i manage to blacklist the nouveau driver and install bbswitch but i'm not quite happy with the result and strangely, i cannot manage to install any newer kernel, i get an error that the linux-headers failed to install. so if you can bring so more info, i'm quite running out of op

Answer (score 1):

ok i managed to install the kernel 4.10 and nvidia 381. I turn off the dGPU with prime on the nVidia drivers, power consumption is low so ok

however, I have issue with the restart or shutdown, the system crash when i tried to do it. Same problem, i got system freeze when i'm pluging the power cable or any usb device...

this computer is so strange...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of kernel boot params to try:

`nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0 quiet splash`

`nomodeset i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0 quiet splash`

`nolapic`

`maxcpus=1`

and, in case you have a touchscreen,

`modprobe.blacklist=i2c_hid`

In case any of these work, after install upgrade the kernel and install nvidia driver from ubuntu drivers ppa.