# (solved) System freeze when pluging usb device or power cable

Tags: system-installation, system, graphic-drivers, nvidia, crash

I had issue installing Loki but I had it done with the help on an other post

[see the post here for the whole topic](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11692/iso-elementary-update-hwe-stacks-linux-4-8/11769#11769)

I managed to install the kernel 4.10 and nvidia 381. I turn off the dGPU with prime on the nVidia drivers, power consumption is low so ok (don't need the dGPU, i play game on Windows with dual boot)

My laptop configuration : i7 6700HQ, nvidia GTX950m, Samsung SM951 128GB M.2 PCI-e ACHI SSD

However, I have issue with the restart or shutdown, the system crash when i tried to do it. Same problem, i got system freeze when i'm pluging the power cable or any usb device...

Thanks !

Comment: Do you still have some kernel options set, from the previous post?

Answer (score 1):

ok I fix the problem by upgrading to kernel 4.11 and blacklist the nouveau driver and install bbswitch and load it at startup via modules.conf